# Alamofire post request FAILURE error

Tags: php, swift, heroku, alamofire, stripe-payments

I'm currently working with Stripe, trying to send a Stripe token to my backend using Alamofire and Heroku. My code is as follows:

```
func postStripeToken(_ token: STPToken) {

    let URL = "https://limitless-fjord-73001.herokuapp.com/charge.php"
    let params = ["stripeToken": token.tokenId,
                  "amount": Int(self.amountTextField.text!)!,
                  "currency": "usd"] as [String : Any]

    Alamofire.request(URL, method: .post, parameters: params)
        .responseJSON { response in
              print(response.request as Any) // original URL request
              print(response.response as Any) // URL response
              print(response.data as Any) // server data
              print(response.result as Any) // result of response serialization

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }

    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that my response.result is printing as FAILURE (see Line 13 above). Everything else seems to be printing fine, including the token and the lines response.request, response.response, and response.data:

```
    Optional(https://limitless-fjord-73001.herokuapp.com/charge.php)
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600000425400> { URL: https://limitless-fjord-73001.herokuapp.com/charge.php } { status code: 500, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 0;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Mon, 29 May 2017 05:58:35 GMT";
    Server = Apache;
    Via = "1.1 vegur";
} })
Optional(0 bytes)
FAILURE
```

Any ideas on why I may be getting a failure? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell what the problem is from the little you've shown us :)

However, this line:

```
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600000425400> { URL: https://limitless-fjord-73001.herokuapp.com/charge.php } { status code: 500, headers {
```

And more specific this part of the line:

```
status code: 500, headers
```

Seems to indicate that you received an error code 500 from your backend, meaning that there was a server side error of some sort.

So, is there a log file somewhere on your server that you could look at and see if it tells you something?

Hope that gives you something to work with.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I inspected the log and it turned out some of the PHP code I wrote in my backend had syntax errors. Much appreciated.

Comment: @M.Ying Glad you got it solved. Feel free to upvote the answer or mark it as correct if it helped you :)